# Question on how to decrypt adopted storage

Tags: encryption, adoptable-storage

In [this answer post](/a/145446/214311), user [poqdavid](/users/135807/poqdavid) gives an answer on how to decrypt adopted storage. In steps 5 - 8, it says to use a linux computer to perform the commands.

As I don't have a linux computer, I was wondering if those steps can be done on the Android phone, using Busybox and Android Terminal Emulator?  If so, what would be the steps to do it (assuming they differ some from the ones posted there)?

Maybe the better question would be, is there a straight-forward way to decrypt the storage ON THE ANDROID DEVICE, so the SD card doesn't have to be removed and read in another machine?